# Limit repeated access attempts by locking out the user ID after not more than six attempts

Tags: centos-7

i do pam_faillock configuration. But, not working

My configuration is:

this path(/etc/pam.d/system-auth & password-auth)

```
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=6 
auth        [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=6 unlock_time=1800

account     required      pam_faillock.so
```

and, I checked result is correctly:

```
pam_faillock is enabled (audit deny=6 unlock_time=1800)
```

but blocking just three times is incorrect attempt.

What Should I Do?